# Computer Musical Keyboard Recommendation

Tags: music, midi

I have a friend who wants to compose music on his computer, and I plan to buy him an electronic keyboard for his birthday. The problem is, I don't have much of an idea of how to pick a high quality electronic keyboard. These are my guidelines.

- Space does not matter, he has plenty of desk space, so more keys is better
- Keys must be full sized or at least close. He plays the piano already and doesn't want to have to relearn anything
- I would like to keep the cost of this peripheral under $50. (I am willing to go over, but not to a ridiculous degree.)

Comment: For $50, you might get a cheap 25-key model.

Comment: Would you say he is primarily a piano player, or a composer? As a piano player, more keys would be extremely important to me, but I bet most composers would be satisfied with less.

Comment: He is a piano player, he wants to be a composer and a piano player.

Comment: The big deciding factors for most keyboards are weighted keys and key velocity. Does he need either of those?

Answer (score 4):

88-key MIDI keyboards for under $50 are a very rare find. Most decently priced ones only have ~50 keys maximum. Based on your budget, I can only recommend the [M-Audio Keystation 49ES Black](http://www.musiciansfriend.com/keyboards-midi/m-audio-keystation-49es-black-with-ableton-lite#productDetail) (~$65 USD).

**Specifications:**

- 49 full-size keys (velocity-sensitive)
- USB connection for playing virtual instruments and controlling DAWs (also for power)
- Pitch bend, modulation, and octave shift
- Light-weight
- Compatible with iOS for mobile composing

The big downfall with this keyboard though, and one that 99% of $70 MIDI keyboards have, is no weighted keys. To me, weighted keys make or break a keyboard because they are what truly provide the real piano experience. But if your friend is okay without this, then I fully recommend this product.